# xhr object does not have "withCredentials" property in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cors

I want to do CORS requests from a client page. In [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/client.html) there is a table which says that Firefox (v 46. and newer) and Chrome (v 51. and newer) both support CORS.
In [html5rocks.com](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-making-a-cors-request) they say that you can check if a browser supports CORS by checking that a created XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property (let's leave IE out of it for now). So I wrote a very simple function that creates an xhr object and checks for the "withCredentials" property and loads the result on the console, and I call the function via an html button, like this:

```js
'use strict';

var corsPostRequest = function(){

    console.log("test");
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var lookInside = xhr.hasOwnProperty("withCredentials");
    console.log(lookInside);
    
    if (xhr.hasOwnProperty("withCredentials")) {
        console.log("we \'re good to go..");
    }
};// end of corsPostRequest
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="javascripts/corsTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="submit_entry" onclick="corsPostRequest()">POST</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I'm getting in the console is:

test

false

which means that the xhr object does not have the "withCredentials" property and consequently cors isn't possible (?). I have tried this in both Firefox (v 50.0) and Chrome (v 54.0.2840.71) but I'm getting the same result, although both browsers should do otherwise, at least according to the link I mentioned above. So I want to ask:

1) Can this be a problem of windows 10 browsers (on which I'm operating)?
2) Is there any way to do cors under these circumstanses?

Comment: just assign it. all modern browser support cors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> xhr.hasOwnProperty("withCredentials")

Your mistake here is that you are assuming it is an own property and not a getter/setter pair inherited from a prototype.

```
"withCredentials" in xhr // true
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This evil JSLint suggested i should use hasOwnProperty instead, and I didn't pay attention to this sutlety. And I thought I had seen enough from JSLint...